# Show notification in certain times

Tags: flutter, awesome-notifications

I want to build a flutter app which will show notification when it's time for prayer.
From a api I'm getting the prayer time.
And with awesome_notification package I'm showing notification for a certain time.
Now I have created a function from where it will return the time.

```
   dateTimeFormat() async {

    if (DateFormat('hh:mm').format(DateTime.now()) ==
        _prayerRes.mainData.first.timings.asr.substring(0, 5)) {
      namajName = "Asar";
      return _prayerRes.mainData.first.timings.asr.substring(0, 5);
    } else if (DateFormat('hh:mm').format(DateTime.now()) ==
        _prayerRes.mainData.first.timings.dhuhr.substring(0, 5)) {
      namajName = "Johar";
      return _prayerRes.mainData.first.timings.dhuhr.substring(0, 5);
    } else if (DateFormat('hh:mm').format(DateTime.now()) ==
        _prayerRes.mainData.first.timings.fajr.substring(0, 5)) {
      namajName = "Fazar";
      return _prayerRes.mainData.first.timings.fajr.substring(0, 5);
    } else if (DateFormat('hh:mm').format(DateTime.now()) ==
        _prayerRes.mainData.first.timings.isha.substring(0, 5)) {
      namajName = "Isha";
      return _prayerRes.mainData.first.timings.isha.substring(0, 5);
    } else if (DateFormat('hh:mm').format(DateTime.now()) ==
        _prayerRes.mainData.first.timings.maghrib.substring(0, 5)) {
      namajName = "Magrib";
      return _prayerRes.mainData.first.timings.maghrib.substring(0, 5);
    }
    // else if (DateFormat('hh:mm').format(DateTime.now()) == "09:52" )
    //   {
    //     return "09:52";
    //   }
    // else if (DateFormat('hh:mm').format(DateTime.now()) == "09:53" )
    //   {
    //     return "09:53";
    //   }
    else if (DateFormat('hh:mm').format(DateTime.now()) == "10:25" )
      {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("testing ================= ${DateFormat('hh:mm').format(DateTime.now())}");
        }
        return "10.25";
      }

    
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("testing2 ================= ${DateFormat('hh:mm').format(DateTime.now())}");
    }
  else
{
  return "10:26";
}
  }
```

Now the problem is when I call this function it always returning the else statement and it only works one time.
I need to trigger this function when I it's time for prayer and returning the prayer time.
How to do that in flutter?